# The Nice-answer Badge should be awarded based on upvotes only

Tags: feature-request, badges, nice-answer

I am adding this as a feature-request or a suggestion.

Considering that most of the answers however good they may be will be voted down(revenge voting), Can the mod's or admins consider that a nice-answer badge be based on upvotes rather than score total?

I mean a good answer with 14 upvotes and 5 downvotes should still be a nice-answer even though it has score of 9 only. There is too much revenge downvoting happening and if we award badges like this then maybe it will encourage the member's.

Comment: Moderators can't explicitly hand out badges and stuff if that's what you're getting at.

Comment: Where did you get that good answer get revenge votes? That is selfom the case.

Comment: No thats not what i meant. I meant that badges should mostly be awarded based on upvotes rather than downvotes.

Comment: Revenge downvoting or downvote trolls are still not so common, unless you can prove otherwise?

Comment: Well proving it is difficult, but they do exist. Im sure we have all encountered them. I mean im back on SO after 2 yrs, but i did have a previous account 2 yrs back and was often a victim of revenge downvoting

Comment: @MarsOne - I wasn't here 2 years ago, but throughout the last year I did not encounter any revenge voting.  In fact if I even wanted to inspire people to take personal revenge at me (other than provoking them through the content of the answer itself), I don't know how I would exactly make myself that important to them.  Maybe you mean something specific by "revenge downvoting" that isn't yet completely clear.

Comment: If there is a revenge downvoting problem, it needs to be solved. ([Except it already is](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829)). We should not change the badge system to work around it.

Comment: Even if revenge voting is still happening, how many people did you tick off to get 5 revenge downvotes on a single answer?

Answer (score 17):

I completely disagree. The down-votes are more likely due to inaccuracies in the answer, not revenge voting.

A "nice answer" must have the consensus of the community. Not just 10 über-keen people.

Comment: Hooray, [a nice answer badge](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/23/nice-answer?userid=192221)! :-P